# Can WebRTC be used to broadcast from one machine and view on another machine?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, live, live-streaming, broadcasting

I have been trying to work with WebRTC for live streaming it on one machine and view it on another machine. The thing is i am able to broadcast and view it on same machine, but with different machines it not working. Can anyone guide me through it to stream from one machine and view it on another?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible issues: if your machines are not in the same network then you have to use STUN/TURN server so that the machines could find each other. You can try to use these:

```
stun.l.google.com:19302
stun1.l.google.com:19302
stun2.l.google.com:19302
stun3.l.google.com:19302
stun4.l.google.com:19302
```

Also this example of using STUN might be helpful: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/